Getting namespace from a obo-formatted text file
I want a way to extract the namespace associated with each GO term from files in the OBO format:

I have tried using a obo converter to txt file https://github.com/PNNL-Comp-Mass-Spec/OBO-Data-Converter but I cannot. I have also tried using the R package "ontologyIndex" but nothing works. Any help is more than welcome

Please provide a little more info. How/where is that list saved? Do you have a local data base or is it a text file? Or maybe an online db? If you used code please provide that too. That helps to get a starting point on how to tackle the problem.

Also, what output do you have in mind? More specifically what does want to get their namespace mean? Save them in a data.frame, create a simple vector? Associate them with an existing data.frame?

Making some assumptions

The .obo file is a local text file
The format is defined as




[Term]
 




id:
GO:0000070


name:
mitotic sister chromatid segregation


namespace:
biological_process


alt_id:
GO:0016359


def:
"The cell cycle process in which replicated homologous chromosomes are organized and then physically separated and apportioned to two sets during the mitotic cell cycle. Each replicated chromosome, composed of two sister chromatids, aligns at the cell equator, paired with its homologous partner. One homolog of each morphologic type goes into each of the resulting chromosome sets." [GOC:ai, GOC:jl]


subset:
goslim_pombe


synonym:
"mitotic chromosome segregation" EXACT []


synonym:
"mitotic sister-chromatid adhesion release" NARROW []


is_a:
GO:0000819 ! sister chromatid segregation


is_a:
GO:1903047 ! mitotic cell cycle process


relationship:
part_of GO:0140014 ! mitotic nuclear division


...
...



etc
Reading the file
dat <- read.delim("go.obo", header=F)

Getting a data frame format from non-repeated terms
head(
do.call(rbind, 
  apply(cbind(grep("\\[Term]", dat$V1) + 1, 
              grep("\\[Term]", dat$V1) - 1 + 
                diff(c(grep("\\[Term]", dat$V1), nrow(dat)))), 1, \(x){
    res <- data.table::tstrsplit(dat[x[1]:x[2],], ": ")
    id <- grep("^id|name|namespace|def|is_obso", res[[1]])
    `length<-`(as.list(res[[2]][id]), 5)})) |> 
  data.frame() |> 
  setNames(c("id", "name", "namespace", "definition", "is_obsolete")))

output
          id                                                     name
1 GO:0000001                                mitochondrion inheritance
2 GO:0000002                         mitochondrial genome maintenance
3 GO:0000003                                    obsolete reproduction
4 GO:0000005                    obsolete ribosomal chaperone activity
5 GO:0000006    high-affinity zinc transmembrane transporter activity
6 GO:0000007 low-affinity zinc ion transmembrane transporter activity
           namespace
1 biological_process
2 biological_process
3 biological_process
4 molecular_function
5 molecular_function
6 molecular_function
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               definition
1                                         The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cytoskeleton. [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:11389764]
2                                                                                                      The maintenance of the structure and integrity of the mitochondrial genome; includes replication and segregation of the mitochondrial chromosome. [GOC:ai, GOC:vw]
3                                                                     OBSOLETE. The production of new individuals that contain some portion of genetic material inherited from one or more parent organisms. [GOC:go_curators, GOC:isa_complete, GOC:jl, ISBN:0198506732]
4                                                          OBSOLETE. Assists in the correct assembly of ribosomes or ribosomal subunits in vivo, but is not a component of the assembled ribosome when performing its normal biological function. [GOC:jl, PMID:12150913]
5 Enables the transfer of zinc ions (Zn2+) from one side of a membrane to the other, probably powered by proton motive force. In high-affinity transport the transporter is able to bind the solute even if it is only present at very low concentrations. [TC:2.A.5.1.1]
6                                                                                                                                                          Enables the transfer of a solute or solutes from one side of a membrane to the other according to the reaction
  is_obsolete
1        NULL
2        NULL
3        true
4        true
5        NULL
6        NULL


That is quite useful thanks. You saved my day. I just want that a data frame where I could extract the namespace associated to an specific GO term so I would have an overview of the functions associated to my fungal genome

Do you have to do it in R?
If not, you can use fastobo, in both Rust and Python
Example for the python library:
import fastobo
import requests

res = requests.get("http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/ms.obo", stream=True)
doc = fastobo.load(res.raw)

for elem in doc:
    if isinstance(elem, fastobo.term.TermFrame):
        for val in elem:
            if "namespace" in str(val):
                print(elem.id, val)


